# How to check target OS version in Deployment Info in Swift code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have my own private framework for iOS 13 or later.
I am using this framework for apps on iOS 12 or earlier as special feature for iOS 13.
I needed to set the target OS of the framework same as the apps' in order to avoid link error at runtime on old OS.

Since I cannot write comments for Xcode build settings, I want to check this in my code.
How can I check target OS version in Swift?

Thanks

Comment: You can set the target to iOS 12 and check an available API via if #available(iOS 13, *)

Comment: if #available(iOS 13, *)  statement will be a runtime code, right?
I want to check it at compile time.

Comment: Since your framework obviously works with both iOS 12 & iOS 13, setting the deployment target to iOS 12 and doing the suggested `#available` checks should suffice. Is there a reason you need to make the deployment target "dynamic"?

Comment: I have a characteristics to "modify" meaningless settings. So I need to put the comment of the reason why I set the target to that version but I cannot. Then I need to check it by code instead of comments

Answer (score 0):

I should set target OS to iOS 13 for my private framework and use weak-linked symbol.
No comments and no compile-time checks are needed.

Frameworks and Weak Linking https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html